# Ideas to implement dynamic parallel build using jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to run a set of tasks for a build in parallel, The tasks for the build are dynamic it may change. I need some help in the implementation of that below are the details of it.

I tasks details for a build will be generated dynamically in an xml which will have information of which tasks has to be executed in parallel/serial

example:

say there is  a build A.

Which had below task and the order of execution , first task 1 has to be executed next task2 and task3 will be executed in parallel and next is task 4

task1
task2,task3
task4

These details will be in an xml dynamically generated , how can i parse that xml and schedule task accordingly using pipeline plugin. I need some idea to  start of with.

Answer (score 16):

You can use Groovy to read the file from the workspace ([`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace)) and then generate the map containing the different closures, similar to the following:

```java
parallel(
  task2: {
    node {
      unstash('my-workspace')
      sh('...')
    }
  },
  task3: {
    node {
      unstash('my-workspace')
      sh('...')
    }
  }
}
```

In order to generate such data structure, you simply iterate over the task data read using XML parsing in Groovy over the file contents you read previously.

By occasion, I gave a talk about pipelines yesterday and included very similar example ([presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/jenkins-pipelines-67473540), slide 34ff.). In contrast, I read the list of "tasks" from another command output. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/6a2599ba0a8626500bbcf25ae5ad198e621e2e57/src/org/typo3/chefci/v1/TestKitchen.groovy#L28-L69) (I avoid pasting all of this here and instead refer to this off-site resource).

The kind of magic bit is the following:

```java
def parallelConverge(ArrayList<String> instanceNames) {
    def parallelNodes = [:]

    for (int i = 0; i < instanceNames.size(); i++) {
        def instanceName = instanceNames.get(i)
        parallelNodes[instanceName] = this.getNodeForInstance(instanceName)
    }

    parallel parallelNodes
}

def Closure getNodeForInstance(String instanceName) {
    return {
        // this node (one per instance) is later executed in parallel
        node {
            // restore workspace
            unstash('my-workspace')

            sh('kitchen test --destroy always ' + instanceName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you've read the file with `readFile`, how can you parse it and iterate over the results? the Pipeline DSL seems to take away a lot of useful tools; I would like to parse a JSON file to determine which builds to trigger, but I can't use `JSON` or `JsonSlurper` from within a Pipeline definition.

Comment: Please ask a separate question, @jayhendren. Seems you're using declarative pipelines.. Only scripted pipelines provide infinite possibilites!

Comment: I posted my question as a comment since it appeared to be an important part of the question that wasn't addressed in your answer.  Thanks for the tip on scripted Pipelines; I'm pretty new to Pipelines and still don't quite grok the differences between the two.

Comment: Don't get your point. The `for` loop is not enough of such iteration? You have basically a Groovy problem to solve at this point (interpreting the file's content).

Comment: Right. I'm asking, "how can you parse a structured file in a Jenkinsfile/Pipeline script"? The Pipeline DSL doesn't appear to have facilities for parsing structured files such as XML, JSON, etc.

Comment: Oh there's e.g. [`readJson`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace). Other than that, use Groovy code. Enough of the off-topic commenting. Please ask your own question, they are for free ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help @StephenKing!  Yes, this has become its own question now. `readJSON` was what I was looking for; it appears there are similar facilities for other structured file types.